# How to concatenate a dictionary of pandas DataFrames into a signle DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have three DataFrames containing each a single row

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame( {'A':[3], 'B':[2], 'C':[1], 'D':[0]} )
dfB = pd.DataFrame( {'A':[9], 'B':[3], 'C':[5], 'D':[1]} )
dfC = pd.DataFrame( {'A':[3], 'B':[4], 'C':[7], 'D':[8]} )
```

for instance dfA is

```
   A  B  C  D
0  3  2  1  0
```

I organize them in a dictionary:

```
data = {'row_1': dfA, 'row_2': dfB, 'row_3': dfC}
```

I want to concatenate them into a single DataFrame

```
ans = pd.concat(data)
```

which returns

```
         A  B  C  D
row_1 0  3  2  1  0
row_2 0  9  3  5  1
row_3 0  3  4  7  8
```

whereas I want to obtain this

```
      A  B  C  D
row_1 3  2  1  0
row_2 9  3  5  1
row_3 3  4  7  8
```

That is to say I want to "drop" an index column.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with second level and parameter `drop=True`:

```
df = ans.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print (df)
       A  B  C  D
row_1  3  2  1  0
row_2  9  3  5  1
row_3  3  4  7  8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset index:

```
pd.concat(data).reset_index(level=-1,drop=True)
```

Output:

```
       A  B  C  D
row_1  3  2  1  0
row_2  9  3  5  1
row_3  3  4  7  8
```